# Tkinter root.after variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter entry where i can change the root.after delay amount, but i get an error that i don't quite understand. I am pretty new to python and especially classes, so i don't know what the problem is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kasper Holm\OneDrive\Python\workBot.py", line 52, in <module>
    window = Bot(root)      # makes passes window to the 'master' argument of the class 'Bot'.
  File "C:\Users\Kasper Holm\OneDrive\Python\workBot.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.root.after(self.timeAmount, self.running)
  File "C:\Users\Kasper Holm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 757, in after
    return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "PY_VAR1": must be cancel, idle, info, or an integer
```

This is the error it gives me, and here is my code.

```
import pyautogui as pag
from tkinter import *


class Bot:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.statusVar = StringVar()
        self.timeAmount = IntVar()
        self.timeAmount.set(2000)   # this sets the default amount of time between actions

        statusLabel = Label(master, textvariable=self.statusVar).grid(row=0, column=1)
        botStart = Button(master, text='Start', command=self.start_bot).grid(row=1, column=1)
        botStop = Button(master, text='Stop', command=self.stop_bot).grid(row=2, column=1)

        timeEntry = Entry(master)
        timeEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)     # time between actions (not done yet)

        timeButton = Button(master, text='Set delay', command=self.timeAmount.set(timeEntry.get()))
        timeButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.root = master
        self.active = False

        self.root.after(self.timeAmount, self.running)

    def running(self):
        if self.active:
            # pag.moveTo(2715, 450)       # moves the mouse to the bot-commands channel and clicks.
            # pag.click(3006, 988)        # moves the mouse to the chat bar.
            # pag.typewrite('.work')
            # pag.typewrite(['enter'])    # typing enter this way will press the enter button instead of typing enter.
            print(pag.position())

        self.root.after(self.timeAmount, self.running)

    def start_bot(self):     # method for starting the bot.
        self.active = True
        self.statusVar.set('Started')

    def stop_bot(self):      # method for stopping the bot.
        self.active = False
        self.statusVar.set('Stopped')


root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x200')
root.title('Gamble bot')
root.attributes("-topmost", True)     # makes sure the window is always on top.

window = Bot(root)      # makes passes window to the 'master' argument of the class 'Bot'.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.timeAmount` is `IntVar` - to get value from `IntVar` (and  similar) you have to use `.get()` - `self.root.after(self.timeAmount.get(), self.running)`

Comment: `command=` needs "callback" - it means function name without `()` - so `command=self.timeAmount.set(timeEntry.get())` is not correct. It will run `self.timeAmount.set(timeEntry.get())` at start and assign `None` to `command=`. You have to create function or use lambda `command=lambda:self.timeAmount.set(timeEntry.get())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.timeAmount` is an object, not a number. If you want to use the *value* of the object, you must use the `get` method:

```
self.root.after(self.timeAmount.get(), self.running)
```

You also have several other problems in this line of code:

```
timeButton = Button(master, text='Set delay', command=self.timeAmount.set(timeEntry.get()))
```

It produces the exact same result as this:

```
value = timeEntry.get()
result = self.timeAmount.set(value)
timeButton = Button(master, text='Set delay', command=result)
```

The `command` attribute requires a *callable*. Under most circumstances it is best if you define a function, and put code to execute in the function. Also, in the code you wrote you're getting the value of `timeEntry` just a few milliseconds after creating it, so the user won't have a chance to change the value.

Instead, create a function and then reference that function. For example:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    self.timeEntry = Entry(master)
    timeButton = Button(master, text='Set delay', command=self.set_delay)
    ...

def set_delay(self):
    new_value = self.timeEntry.get()
    self.timeAmount.set(new_value)
```

By putting the code in a function it will be easier to understand and easier to debug.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I guess i didn't quite understand the command attribute, i had thought that it would be a bad idea to create a whole new function just for this one thing. But now i see that that isn't always the case. Thank you very much!